# Live-Build doesn't make iso

Tags: debian, live-usb, livecd

I'm trying to make a Debian live image with live build
here's the switches which i'm using with lb config

> --mode debian \
>   --system live \
>   --interactive shell \
>   --debian-installer live \
>   --architecture amd64 \
>   --updates true \
>   --binary-images iso-hybrid

......
here's the problem
P: Begin building root filesystem image...
P: Preparing squashfs image...
Cannot stat source directory "chroot" because No such file or directory
.......
but the chroot directory exists and i can use it
what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before, you need to run the `lb build` command under root,

At the command line type `su`, enter your root password, then you should be able to type `lb build` which will build your system.

Hope that helps.